Steps involved for packet transit from Router Ingress to Router Egress interface
I am looking to  better understand, what happens within the router when an L3 packet arrives at a router interface and egresses via the exit interface.
For e.g consider the below,
assume Hundred Gig 3/1 is ingress interface, while Hundred Gig 3/2 is the egress interface.
What are sequence of steps that are actually performed , from ingress till egress.
Some of the things, that i have read about are

Performing IPv4 Header checksum
If header checksum is correct, decrement the TTL.
check if TTL is > 0. if not, drop the packet.
Compute and update the new IP header checksum.

but i am looking to understand. more details, in terms of internal transition/sequence of steps/flow diagram that happens within the router. Different vendors/OEMs may have different implemenations, but is there anything generic that i can follow.
One of the references i found here, but is there more generic implemenation, that gives a uber level view.


A full explanation is too big for this forum, but if you google "how ip routing works," and read several articles, you will get the information you need.

This classic Linux iptables diagram may also be informative for you: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

I'm deliberately ignoring L2 details here for simplicity.
A basic router takes the destination IP address and matches it to its routing table, longest prefix first, shortest prefix last. It takes the interface and next-hop gateway from the matched routing table entry and then forwards the packet that way.
A more complex router may do some additional processing, including but not limited to, and not in any particular order

source-route checking
ingress ACL checking
ingress firewall policy checking
IP and/or port translation (NAPT)
policy routing (based on source, protocol)
complex queueing for QoS
egress ACL checking
egress firewall policy checking
encapsulate for tunneling, possibly encrypt

Also, when the ingress packet is addressed to the router itself, it may

process by device management
decapsulate from tunneling, possibly decrypt


In general the following happens:

Find the ingress interface based on VLAN + ingress port. If there is no match, drop the packet.

L2 header processing:



lookup in L2 MAC address database if L2 header termination will be
needed. This is in case packet's destination MAC == MY MAC.

lookup in L2 MAC address table (key is VSI_ID + MAC address - lookup
result is output interface) to forward the frame based on L2 address. (In case of switching/L2VPN service)


2.5. If L2 header was terminated perform MPLS header processing. Here MPLS tunnels are being terminated, or MPLS LFIB lookup is performed to do MPLS label swaps.

L3 header processing:
In case L2 header termination took place (+maybe also MPLS tunnel termination took place) perform L3 lookup in the IP routing database.
The lookup is based on: VRF + IP address key, will give egress interface + L2 encapsulation info (to construct the appropriate L2 header for the next hop router/host). In this stage also TTL is updated (in case of 0, packet is dropped) + L3 header checksum is verified and re-calculated.


Egress packet processing - according to data provided by L2 frame/L3 packet lookup, in case of L3, attach the new L2 header, perform L2 header checksum calculation and send the packet out of the previously found egress interface.

